# GRUB: Fatal! inconsistent data read from (0x84) 0+xxxxxx

Tags: boot, grub2

Can anybody help me with this messages at (before) grub starts booting?

```
.
.
Fatal! inconsistent data read from (0x84) 0+xxxxxx
.
Fatal! inconsistent data read from (0x84) n+yyyyyy
.
(hd0,4)
```

This is running in dual boot with windows 7. Both Windows and Ubuntu are running flawlessly, except for this "errors" list.